# How to toggle "Require password after X minutes after sleep or screen saver begins" setting on MacOS 12 using Terminal?

Tags: macos, security, plist

I'd like to change the value of the "Require password after X minutes after sleep or screen saver begins" option on Mac using Terminal. In some older MacOS versions one could do

```
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -bool true
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay -int 0
```

but nowadays that doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know how to do that now?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867402/macos-10-13-high-sierra-no-longer-stores-screensaver-settings-in-com-apple-scr

Comment: Thanks @dan, that answered my question!